# Построение отчёта в .txt формате в JasperReports Server

Tags: jasperreports

Я использую JasperReports Server 6.4.2. На вкладке «Output Options» окна «New Schedule» у меня есть такой список выходных форматов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я бы хотела добавить на эту форму чекбокс для построения отчёта в .txt формате. Я раскомментировала следующую строку в *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\flows\viewReportBeans.xml* файле:

```
<!--
<entry key="txt" value-ref="txtExporterConfiguration"/>
 -->
```

а также раскомментировала следующие строки:

```
<!-- 
        <bean class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.dto.ByteEnum">
            <property name="code">
                <util:constant static-field="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.domain.ReportJob.OUTPUT_FORMAT_TXT"/>
            </property>
            <property name="labelMessage">
                <value>report.output.txt.label</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
-->
```

в файле *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\flows\reportJobBeans.xml*. После этого я перезагрузила сервер, однако ничего не изменилось - форма "Formats" осталась прежней. Как добавить в эту форму чекбокс "Text only" для построения отчёта в .txt формате?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец я нашла [инструкцию](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-add-txt-exporter-scheduler-output-options-tibco-jasperreports-server-v601-and-newer), как это сделать. Шаги, которых мне не хватало: редактирование файла *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\scripts\scheduler\view\editor\outputTabView.js* и отключение свойства javascript.optimize в файле *WEB-INF\js.config.properties*. После этих действий чекбокс «TXT» в конце концов появился на форме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]